# Query to give nearest value from the data rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table where columns are as shown below `Column B` contains numbers and I want the next column to reflect `Parent` relationship of `Column B` based on data in `Column B`

| Column A | Column B | (Expected or Calculated Field) Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | Null |
| def | 2 | 1 |
| ghil | 3 | 2 |
| jklo | 4 | 3 |
| mnok | 5 | 4 |
| pqrt | 5 | 4 |
| stuv | 5 | 4 |

I tried `Lag` method but it messes with the below numbers where the value is same.
Help please

Comment: Why not `NULLIF(ColumnB-1,0)`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```sql
select  *
,   max(prev) over(order by [column b], [column a]) as parent
from (
    
    select *, case when lag([column b]) over(order by [column b], [column a]) <> [Column B] then lag([column b]) over(order by [column b], [column a]) end as prev
    from (
        VALUES  (N'abc', 1, Null)
        ,   (N'def', 2, N'1')
        ,   (N'ghil', 3, N'2')
        ,   (N'jklo', 4, N'3')
        ,   (N'mnok', 5, N'4')
        ,   (N'pqrt', 5, N'4')
        ,   (N'stuv', 5, N'4')
    ) t ([Column A],[Column B],[(Expected or Calculated Field) Parent])
    ) x
```

You get previous row and if it's different from current, select that, otherwise  NULL. Then on next iteration, you take the maximum value of the previous rows. This would filter out the NULLs.